# How to use NSArrayController to fill data in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c

I want to use NSArrayController to fill the NSTableview, but i am unable to find out the exact procedure.

Answer (score 33):

One way to do this is via KVC, using an NSArrayController to populate an NSTableView.

Example Code:

TestAppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrayController;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *theTable;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrayController;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *theTable;

- (void) populateTable;

@end
```

TestAppDelegate.m

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize arrayController;
@synthesize theTable;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Populate the table once with the data below
    [self populateTable];
}

- (void) populateTable
{
    NSMutableDictionary *value = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // Add some values to the dictionary
    // which match up to the NSTableView bindings
    [value setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"id"];
    [value setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"] forKey:@"name"];

    [arrayController addObject:value];

    [value release];

    [theTable reloadData];
}
@end
```

Now make the bindings in interface builder:

- Create an NSArrayController & connect it to arrayController
- Connect the NSTableView to theTable;
- Select the NSTableView and set TestAppDelegate as its dataSource & delegate
- For each column in the table
- Bind its Value to *arrayController*
- Set the **Controller Key** to *arrangedObjects*
- Set the **Model Key Path** to each key from above (e.g. *id* or *name*)

When run, there should now be a single data row.  (This is untested code, but should give the general idea)

For more help with these bindings check out [this example](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/binding-nsmutablearray-to-nsarraycontroller/).

[Here is also a good example](http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.com/2011/11/simple-nstableview-application-with.html) with pictures of how to create a populated NSTableView.

Comment: Very nice and substantial answer. A few minor technical quibbles, however. With the use of a controller to populate the table view's columns, it isn't necessary to *connect* the table view's dataSource and delegate properties. Also, you're not using KVC in your sample code, you're using *bindings*. While the bindings mechanism is built on KVC (as well as KVO and more), you're not actually using any of the KVC API in your sample because you don't need to.