# how to set setEnabled: for NSButton in an NSTableView

Tags: nstableview, nsbutton

Hi All
I have an NSTableView which has three columns. The first one is a checkbox and the third one is a button. The button 'is enabled' state depends on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

I am setting the table content in the `awakeFromNib` method and I am implementing the checkbox state in the `- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row`  method. I need to find a way `setEnabled:` for the `NSButton`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good way to set button states in an NSTableView is to use an NSArrayController and bind it to the columns of the NSTableView:

- Bind the column that contains the buttons to the NSArrayController (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616945/how-to-use-nsarraycontroller-to-fill-data-in-nstableview))
- Under **Enabled**

  - Set the `Controller Key` to *arrangedObjects*
  - Set the `Model Key Path` to the NSArrayController's button state.  For example, let's call it *enabled* .

Now in the class where you have the NSArrayController and the NSTableView delegate, do something like this after you click a checkbox:

```
- (void)updateArrayControllerWithButtonState: (BOOL)isEnabled
{
    // theTable is the NSTableView instance variable
    NSInteger row = [theTable clickedRow];

    // Get the array of values that populates the table
    NSMutableDictionary *arrayValues = [[theArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];

    // Actually change the NSArrayController's value to match
    [arrayValues setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[model isEnabled]] forKey:@"enabled"];

    [theTable reloadData];
}
```

Provided you set up your bindings properly for the NSArrayController & NSTableView, this function should update the current state of the button to match that of the NSArrayController.

This code is untested but should shed some light on the general idea.